# Using C# Type as generic

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create a generic list from a specific Type that is retrieved from elsewhere:

```
Type listType; // Passed in to function, could be anything
var list = _service.GetAll<listType>();
```

However I get a build error of:

```
The type or namespace name 'listType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Is this even possible or am I setting foot onto C# 4 Dynamic territory?

As a background: I want to automatically load all lists with data from the repository. The code below get's passed a Form Model whose properties are iterated for any IEnum (where T inherits from DomainEntity). I want to fill the list with objects of the Type the list made of from the repository.

```
public void LoadLists(object model)
{
    foreach (var property in model.GetType()
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty))
   {
        if (IsEnumerableOfNssEntities(property.PropertyType))
        {
            var listType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

            var list = _repository.Query<listType>().ToList();

            property.SetValue(model, list, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a variable as a generic type/method parameter, however you can do some simple things using reflection, for example you can construct list this way:

```
Type listType = typeof(int);
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(listType));
```

Not sure if it will be helpful, since you'll need to cast that list to something to make it useful, and you cant simply cast it to a generic type/interface without specifying generic type parameters.

You can still add/enumerate such list by casting it to non-generic versions of interfaces ICollection, IList, IEnumerable.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the case. I'm consuming the list from a method<T>() elsewhere in the system, so can't create the list from scratch. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can also call a generic method using reflection, but you'll still have the same problems with result. Check this article about dynamic generic method invocation: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/InvokeGenericMethods.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it the type that listType is

```
var list = _repository.Query<typeof(listType)>().ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's already a Type. typeof() is used to convert the name of a class, interface, etc (i.e. as if you were going to access a static method on it).